# Relating two tables

Tags: sql, firebird

I have created tables T1 with columns( id as Primary key and name) and T2 with columns( id as primary key, name, t_id as foreign key references T1(id)) . I Inserted some values from inputs from a Windows form. After querying SELECT * FROM T2; using isql, all the values in the foreign key column are null instead of duplicating values in T1(id) because of the relationship created. Is they anything I have left out or need to add?  The primary key of both tables are autoincremented.

Comment: Show the `insert` query of `T2` table

Comment: INSERT INTO T2(name) VALUES (textbox.Text) ;hThe primary key(id)  is autoincremented by a generator.

Comment: You need to insert data for `t_id` column as well else it will be `NULL`.  `INSERT INTO T2(name,t_id) VALUES (textbox.Text,'someval')`

Comment: TI(id) is autoincremented. Is there a way to get the last inserted value, save it and pass it?

Comment: Yes, you need to use [`INSERT ... RETURNING ... `](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-insert.html#langrefupd25-insert-returning)

Comment: Mark Rotteveel how do I store the value it returns and insert it into T2

Comment: That depends, as it stands you haven't provided sufficient context to answer that. You usually retrieve it inside your programming language of choice and then use that value to execute the next statement. If you want to do this in a script, you will need to wrap it in an [`EXECUTE BLOCK`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/reference_material/html/langrefupd25-execblock.html) and use the PSQL `INTO ...` clause.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing auto-incremented keys and relationship uses.

Auto-incremented keys (or generally talking, fields) just help you when you are inserting a new record on the table of the key. But when you are inserting a new record that makes a reference to a record in another table, then you must specify that record, using the foreign key field. Or in your case, the user that is inserting the "name" in T2 must say which one record on T1 that "name" in T2 is making a reference.

Your confusion on the relationship is that you are thinking that an established relationship will enforce the *use* of that values automatically. But the relationship just enforce the *validation* of the values. So, the field t_id in T2 will not use the value of the last record of T1 automatically. But if you try to insert a value that do not exist in T1 in the field t_id, the relationship will not let you do.

So, answering your question, what you left out and need to add?
You left out the part of the code that insert the value on the t_id field of T2 table.

Let me try to explain using an example that is more common.

The most common case of this is that the application insert first the T1 record and then when the user is inserting T2, the application provide a way to the user to choose which one T1 record his T2 record is referencing.

Suppose T1 is a publishers table and T2 is a book table. User insert a publisher, and when it is inserting a book it can choose which one publisher publish that book.

Answer (score 0):

Field  "ID" of Customers will be AUTOINCREMENT by default in table create using Event BeforeInsert on table CUSTOMERS.  LOOK AT

CREATE TRIGGER nametrigger FOR  nametable
  ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
  AS
  BEGIN
    IF (NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN BEGIN
      NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_PK_ID, 1);
    END

END

Now one new record in Customers

INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal','Tom B. Erichsen','Skagen 21','Stavanger','4006','Norway');

Then  ID will be automaticaly one sequencial number from 1 up to last integer or smallint or bigint as you defined in your create table (pay attencion that ID field is not include in FIELDS and VALUES) because TRIGGER

now you can use the dataset (obj) options to link the table MATER and DETAIL  see in help  delphi

or in SQL you can to use PARAMS FIELDS

later insert one new record in table MASTER try...

INSERT INTO  xTable2 (IDcustomersField, ..., ..., ...., ....)
VALUES (  :IDcustomersField, ..., ..., ...., ....);

xTable2 may using one field ID (Primary Key) autoincrement too. this help when DELETING or UPDATING fileds in this table

Then you can say the value to  :IDcustomersField in table detail using 
xQuery.PARAM( 0 ).value  or  xQuery.PARAMBYNAME( IDcustomersField).value  (here im using Query obj as example )

you can to use example with DATASOURCE in code to say the value for IDcustomersField

can to use
Events in SQL

can to use
PROCEDURE IN SQL

DONT FORGOT

you have to create  Relationship between two table ( REFERENCIAL INTEGRITY and PRIMARY KEY in mater table ) NOT NULL FOR TWO FIELDS ON TABLES

I believe that understand me about my poor explanation (i dont speak english

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert the values for t_id manually, after you get the ID's value from the main table T1.
Depending on your logic in the database you also can use a trigger or a stored procedure. Give us more information about what values you expect to have in NAME field in T2 after the insert? Are they duplicates from T1 or independent from T1?
If T1.NAME=T2.NAME, you can automate the process with a trigger

```
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER TR_T1_AI0 FOR T1
ACTIVE AFTER INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T2(NAME, T_ID) 
  VALUES (NEW.NAME, NEW.ID);
END
```

If T2.NAME's value is different from T1.NAME you can use a stored procedure with parameters both names:

```
CREATE ORA ALTER PROCEDURE XXXX(
  P_NAME_T1 TYPE OF T1.NAME,
  P_NAME_T2 TYPE OF T2.NAME)
AS
DECLARE VARIABLE L_ID TYPE OF T1.ID;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T1(NAME)
  VALUES (:p_NAME_T1)
  RETURNING ID INTO:L_ID;   

  INSERT INTO T2(NAME, T_ID)
  VALUES (:P_NAME_T2, :l_ID);
END
```

You can use both statements from the stored procedure directly in your program if it supports the returning syntax. If not, you need an additional query with  `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GENERATOR_FOR_T1 FROM RDB$DATABASE;` and use the value returned from it in both INSERT statements.